# Too many connections issue on wordpress, using database cache, non shared host

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm at my wits end here.
A client has a wordpress website that is expected to have heavy traffic incoming next saturday. I was asked to find out if the site can handle the load, and using JMeter my answer is "no", as it keeps having database connection issues.

Now, for the configurations and issue I'm finding.

This is a cloud hosting that as far as I could find out is not shared, using a standard apache / linux configuration. Mysql's "max_connections" variable is 1000, and my tests fail even at something like 50 connections / sec. SHOW PROCESSLIST shows nothing out of the usual, at worst a couple threads sleeping for 3 seconds, but no hanged queries or anything of the sort.

Wordpress itself is a fairly standard configuration. Does use a couple plugins, the one most obviously affecting database performance being woocommerce. Everything else is a gallery plugin then some minor stuff like contact forms. 10 plugins total.

For cache I'm using W3 Total Cache's page, object and database caches. I'm even forcing caches for queries that aren't on the default configuration of W3 cache like COUNT() queries, and it seems to be working as it's showing all queries on homepage cached.

However, JMETER shows as high as 50% failure at 50/sec connections. It's not exactly consistent, sometimes goes up and down but still way above what would be considered acceptable and as I understand way below the server's 1000 connections limit. Still getting too many connections issue. If I turn off cache it goes to like 90%, so that's clearly helping.

At this point, I'm not sure how to further mitigate this problem. Even if I disable every plugin, the number stays above 1% since the homepage then displays barely anything, but obviously I cannot just disable all plugins as that pretty much breaks the website. I can hopefully disable a couple or temporarily force a static response out of them, but there has to be some underlying issue causing this, since I'm not sure that would even be acceptable for the client.

How could I further debug this problem? Is it possible that each plugin creates it's own new connection, for example? Is there a way I can debug, for example, how many connections were opened at the end of a script execution?

Comment: My guess would be that the connections are not being closed, so stay open.

Comment: Maybe something can be changed in php.ini. Do you have access to that? Off the top of my head, you might look at max connections there as well as max memory and max script run time (or whatever they're called...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into using query monitor to see exactly what code is running what kind of queries how long they take etc.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

This is a great tool for benchmarking performance optimizing templates and various calls.